# Formatting SQL result as a sum

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is the query I'm using to gather daily values from three different "addresses", which reference different sensors in our system.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    LEFT(changes.date_time, 6) AS 'date',
    changes.address AS 'address',
    (CASE WHEN changes.address IN (18) THEN - MAX(changes.value * types.multiplier) ELSE MAX(changes.value * types.multiplier) END) AS 'value'
FROM sensor.changes
INNER JOIN sensor.types ON changes.type = types.idx
WHERE
    changes.address IN (1, 4, 8)
    AND changes.date_time >= '12110100000000'
    AND changes.date_time <= '13050100000000'
GROUP BY LEFT(changes.date_time, 6),
    changes.address
ORDER BY changes.idx;
```

The first date contains the following values, with subsequent dates carrying the same addresses:

```
date   address value
130203 1        0.0160
130203 4        0.1220
130203 8       -0.0070
```

I want to combine these three values, address 1+4+8, into a single row for that date. I've attempted a SUM on the "value" column, but that results in an SQL error: `#1111 - Invalid use of group function`. Taking out the second GROUP BY column results in one value per date, but the value is not a sum of those values. Using a second query to format the result is OK, but I would prefer if the math was done in the first query because the database server is not local.

EDIT: to clarify what I need as the result:

```
date   address value
130203 1       0.131
```

The integer under the `address` column in this case doesn't matter.

Comment: What about the `value`? What should your output look like?  (hint: _don't_ just add a `GROUP BY date`, though MySQL will allow you to)

Comment: Thanks, I've added the desired result. The first `GROUP BY` column is used in almost all my queries because there's actually many values per address per day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add a grouping clause.

```
SELECT Resdate,SUM(Res.address),SUM(Res.value)
FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT
    LEFT(changes.date_time, 6) AS 'date',
    changes.address AS 'address',
    (CASE WHEN changes.address IN (18) THEN - MAX(changes.value * types.multiplier) ELSE MAX(changes.value * types.multiplier) END) AS 'value'
FROM sensor.changes
INNER JOIN sensor.types ON changes.type = types.idx
WHERE
    changes.address IN (1, 4, 8)
    AND changes.date_time >= '12110100000000'
    AND changes.date_time <= '13050100000000'
GROUP BY LEFT(changes.date_time, 6),
    changes.address
ORDER BY changes.idx
) AS Res
GROUP BY Res.Date
```

Comment: Thank you! With some minor tweaks to the syntax this worked perfectly.